# sanic How to do dependency injection?

Tags: python-3.x, sanic

In my `app.py` I have the following code:

```
from sanic import Sanic
my_dep = load_production_dep()
app = Sanic()


@app.route("/")
def hello(request):
    return my_dep.hello()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, debug=True)
```

How do I inject this `my_dep` into my sanic app instance? With the current setup above, I can't quite test my code, as I have route that relies on the global dependency loaded in the module.

In other words: how do I restructure this simple app so that it's easily testable?

Comment: app.my_dep = load_production_dep()

Answer (score 0):

I can be solved with [blueprints](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/blueprints.html) and app factories.

```
# routes.py
from sanic import Blueprint
bp = Blueprint('my_blueprint')

@bp.route("/")
def hello(request):
    return my_dep.hello()

# app.py
def make_app():
    from sanic import Sanic
    from routes import bp

    my_dep = load_production_dep()
    app = Sanic()
    app.blueprint(bp)
    return app

# test.py
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.test_app = make_app() # or you can make your own factory for test app specifically 
    def test_foobar(self):
        ...
```